# From Form1.Chart1 to Report.rdlc in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

Is there anyway to send chart from `form1` chart to `report.rdlc`?
Here is my chart and reportviewer .
[image]

i want to send chart1 to reportviewer or send chart1 parameters to chart1.report.rdlc ?

Comment: I've never worked with `report.rdlc`, but can you include a bitmap in the report? In that case you could capture the `Graphics` object of your chart, and use it to draw the chart to a `bitmap` you create. You could then include the `bitmap` in your report. As I said i've never worked with reports, but i'm guessing there must be a way to include images in it.

Comment: I never try that one. It's hard to make a code in expressions from `report.rdlc` and it's not the same code that i'm using it's like different code like `=Count(!Field.X_Axis.value)` .  Can you elaborate how to do the bitmap in the report and capture the chart1 from form1 to draw it on report.rdlc as image? right?